# Quality versus histogram bin size

Tags: image-processing

I just want to know what is the optimal number of Histogram bins that can give a high quality image in terms of contrast without loosing most of the details. For example we can produce equalized images using matlab's histeq(I,n) function specifying different values for n such as 32,64,128,256 etc. The lesser the value of n i.e lesser the number of bins used, the better is the contrast. It is said in order to get a high contrast image the histogram should be uniformly distributed, as well as, as flat as possible. If we use 256 bins we never get a flat histogram, so it means the contrast is not so high but I think the image contains much more details and if we use 64 bins, we get high contrast image (as the histogram is flat in this case) but will contain lesser details. So I am confused as to what is the optimal size of n. Is there any formula for it or how do we decide it. I am sorry to say that as I am new to this site, so may be this question is not intended for this site. Please move the question to the required site if necessary. Thank you.